# Pandas dataframe from list with merged index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am new to python, so call me a noob but I cannot find a clear answer. I want to obtain a pandas dataframe from a list of lists with merged indices. I am running a loop and the numbe rof observations (here arbitrarily 3) could differ in each run. This holds also true for the dates. I'm sorry but I could not manage a more real life example.

```
import pandas as pd

# First create a list of lists
my_list = [[] for i in range(3)]

# Now fill the list in a loop

for i in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
        my_list[i].append(pd.DataFrame({"signal_%d" % i: [i], "date": pd.Timestamp('2015-10-26 16:24:08.572000')}))

>>> my_list

[[                     date  signal_0
0 2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         0,                      date  signal_0
0 2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         0,                      date  signal_0
0 2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         0], [                     date  signal_1
0 2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         1,                      date  signal_1
0 2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         1,                      date  signal_1
0 2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         1], [                     date  signal_2
0 2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         2,                      date  signal_2
0 2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         2,                      date  signal_2
```

How can i obtain the following dataframe

```
>>> perfect_df
                         signal_0  signal_1  signal_2
2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         0         1         2
2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         0         1         2  
2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         0         1         2
```

pd.DataFrame(my_list) doen't seem to work.

Thanks in advance! 
Patrik

Comment: Why do you use a list first?? Why not directly the dataframe?

Comment: It's an example. The list in my real code gets filled in a loop. Maybe you can show me how to fill the dataframe in a loop? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless i'm missing something, you can build directly the dataframe

```
In [65]: pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.to_datetime(['2015-10-26 16:24:08.572'] * 3),
    data={
        'signal_0': 0,
        'signal_1': 1,
        'signal_2': 2
    }
)
Out[65]: 
                         signal_0  signal_1  signal_2
2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         0         1         2
2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         0         1         2
2015-10-26 16:24:08.572         0         1         2
```

Comment: During the loop I don't know how many rows will be added to the list, In particular the number of observations might differ in the three columns and they might or might not have the same dates attached. So it's not about creating a dataframe from the spot, but handling the indices.